# Image Field Caption not showing on inserted images

Tags: media

I've added Image Field Caption module to my site, and the caption field now shows up underneath each image field perfectly. However, when I go to the page, the caption doesn't show up. From what I can tell, the SPACE for the caption is there, but the actual text is not.

I should mention I'm using a custom framework from my university and can't immediately get to the code.

I found an old thread about this: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2013-08-20/image-field-caption-not-showing-up

This particular field is an "additional images" field.  When I SHOW that field via the Content Type > Field > Display, the images all pile on the bottom of the page, but the caption IS there.  However, I obviously want to be able to put the images onto the page wherever I want and still want the caption to show up.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Might be a css issue, switch to the default "Barktik" Drupal theme and see if its missing there too or not. If it's not missing here, then def a css issue with your theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't yet have access to the files to do local development, so I can't change themes right now, but I'll look at the css and see if anything is obvious.

Comment: You could use a chrome extension like [web developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) to strip/block all CSS with your browser and see if the caption is printed on the page.